# Cannot use `roles` method default of Laravel Permission Spatie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I install spatie/laravel-permission, but i cannot use `role` method default of `spaite`.
In `User` model I was add `HasRoles`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    const ACTIVE = 'active';
    const LOCKED = 'locked';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'status',
        'email',
        'password',
        'password_updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

//    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
//    {
//        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Role::class, 'user_has_roles', 'user_id');
//    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

if I define new `roles` method override method of spatie (comment section), I will get roles from code:

```php
\App\Models\User::find(1)->first()->roles()->get()->toArray()
```

result is:

```sh
array:1 [
  0 => array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "admin"
    "guard_name" => "api"
    "created_at" => "2021-10-19T18:23:20.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-10-19T18:23:20.000000Z"
    "pivot" => array:2 [
      "user_id" => 1
      "role_id" => 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

but if I use `roles` method default of spatie code below not result, this is result when i run:

```sh
[]
```

I have searched a lot but no results, hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: what is the result of  ```auth()->user()->roles;```

Comment: result is: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1096
  #items: []
}`

Answer (score 0):

Spatie Laravel Permission does not use `roles` method.

The right way:

`$roles = $user->getRoleNames(); // Returns a collection`

Docs: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage

P/s: Anh em cần hỏi thêm gì thì cứ gửi tin nhắn.

Comment: cái hàm role mình nói ở đây là cái ORM để nó nối với bảng users ý bạn, do cái này nó được nối vào không đúng nên 1 loạt các phương thức phía sau cũng không đúng theo. Ví dụ như cái getRoleName mà bạn bảo nếu mình ghi đè lại con role method của Spatie thì nó sẽ ra kết quả là:
```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#361
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => "admin"
  ]
}
```
còn nêu không ghi đè mà để mặc định thì kết quả sẽ ra là: 
```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#361
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: Không cần phải dùng method `role` nữa. Dùng Trait là được:
`use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;`